# Ajax Values to Controller Method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass values to my controller, from my view using ajax.  I am relatively new to using ajax so I need some help figuring this out.

**Full Page**

```
@model ALSummary.Models.MonthReport

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2><strong>Generate Monthly Report</strong></h2>

<br />
<hr />

@Html.BeginForm("Generate", "MonthReports", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "GenerateForm" }){
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Choose AC:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("AC", null, "-- Select AC --", htmlAttributes: new { id = "AC", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Choose Month:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Months", null, "-- Select Month --", htmlAttributes: new { id = "Month", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Year:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Years", null, "-- Select Year --", htmlAttributes: new { id = "Year", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<input type="submit" id="SendToController" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate" />
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SendToController').on('click', function() {
        sendToController();
        return false;
    });
    function sendToController(){
        var selectedAC = $('#AC').val();
        var selectedMonth = $('#Month').val();
        var chosenYear = $('#Year').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Action("Generate", "MonthReports", null),
            data: { 'id' : selectedAC, 'monthValue' : selectedMonth, 'year' : chosenYear },
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){},


        });
    }


</script>
```

Error Message:

[image]

Here is where the red squiggly lines are happenning when I receive the error message:

[image]

Comment: make sure you're returning a false value from the click event per my note in the answer below... otherwise it doesn't cancel the native submit behavior.

Comment: @jdl134679 just updated question again, still receiving error. can you point out anything that you see? It is the whole view page

Comment: @jdl134679 ? i csnt find the issue

Comment: What's the error you're getting now?

Comment: @jdl134679 still the same one.. i think i am confused with the form part.. is the `@Html.BeginForm` needed for a successful ajax submit? why couldn't I just put an event on button click?

Comment: You need a form for the inputs.  Add an event argument to the click event's callback: `$('#SendToController').on('click', function(event) {`, then before the sendToController call put `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: (might help also to re-post the error into the question so others can see... my availability is hit or miss)

Comment: @jdl134679 just updated. I added a picture where it shows the red squiggly lines

Comment: Oooh, that's because the url needs to be in quotes (the rest fix themselves after that).  Anyway, glad to hear you got it working... usually you keep JS in a separate file anyway and pass values to it rather than using razor though.  it's a start anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX and Controller look fine... the error reported is because your javascript function can't be found (isn't present) at the time that the HTML is loaded for the Submit input (usually this is because the JS isn't loaded until after the DOM, my guess is that your script block is at the end of your body and not in the head (which is fine/preferred, just needs to be handled a bit differently)).

I typically prefer to bind events via JS rather than the HTML.  Remove the `onclick="sendToController()"` from your HTML, and add this to your JavaScript:

```
$("#FormID").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendToController();
    return false;   // prevent submit from submitting
});

function sendToController() {
    // your other code here
}
```

Change `FormID` to the ID of the form as required.

Comment: Unobutrisive javascript it is called.

Comment: I updated my question, and am now receving this after changing up my JS a little

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid - see my comment on your updated question

Comment: I got it working, apparently ajax doesn't like razor

Comment: I should have caught it.. the URL needs to be in quotes, so this would have worked:  `url: '@Url.Action("Generate", "MonthReports", null)',`